# Script finds childs when there are none

Tags: if-statement, lua, roblox

So i am making a roblox game with a building system(a pc building system).
It checks if the itemholder where the pc will be installed already has components.
But when the itemholder folder is empty it still says that it found children of the itemholder.

this is the code i am using.
The building system has nothing to do with the bug i think so i wont add that.

```
-- variables that will stay the same
local item = game.ReplicatedStorage.PCCompontents.Cases.FractalDesignC
local itemsHolder = workspace.Desk.ItemsHolder
local componentType = item:GetAttribute("Component")
local PCSpot = workspace.Desk.PC

local function place()
    if #itemsHolder:GetChildren() > 0 then
-- here it says that it found children
        for _, component in itemsHolder:GetChildren() do
-- this doesnt loop doesn't work cause actually there are no children.
            if component:GetAttribute("Component") ~= componentType then
                game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.PlacePCPart:InvokeServer(item, PCSpot.Position, itemsHolder)
            else
                print("This Component Is Already Installed")
            end
        end
    else
        print("test")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.PlacePCPart:InvokeServer(item, PCSpot.Position, itemsHolder)
    end
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(place)
```

the script check if there are children. if there are it loops through every child and check the attribute to see what component it is. else you would be able to install for example 2 motherboards.

I tried multiple ways of going around this but it doesnt work.
The script says there are more than 0 children but there arent.
That is the part where the whole script stops working cause one check isn't working.

Comment: Shouldn't you be wrapping `itemsHolder:GetChildren()` in pairs() or ipairs() or is an iterator? or do things just work differently in Roblox?

Comment: You can do pairs or ipairs or nothing in roblox. But its the if statement that always lets the script through

Comment: i fixed it by changing `if #itemsHolder:GetChildren() > 0 then` to `if itemsHolder:FindFirstChild(itemsHolder:GetChildren()) ~= nil then`